# Automapper custom many-to-one conversion

Tags: c#, mapping, converters, automapper, dto

## Automapper Many To One conversion

How to convert values of many properties from the source object to a single type in destination object?
Can I use in this case [Value Resolvers](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers)? Or maybe there is better solution?

### Documentation

Here is [example](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers) from [documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki) - *one to one conversion*

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Total,
        opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>().FromMember(src => src.SubTotal));
Mapper.CreateMap<OtherSource, OtherDest>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.OtherTotal,
        opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>().FromMember(src => src.OtherSubTotal));

public class CustomResolver : ValueResolver<decimal, decimal> {
// logic here
}
```

### Case

I want to transfer two objects into one (*many to one conversion*). For example:

```
public class Document
{
    public int CurrencyId {get; set;}
    public int ExchangeRateId {get; set;}
}

public class DocumentDto
{
    public Currency Currency {get; set;}
}

public class CurrencyDetails
{
    public Currency Currency {get; private set;}
    public ExchangeRate ExchangeRate {get; private set;}

    public CurrencyDetails(Currency currency, ExchangeRate exchangeRate)
    {
        Currency = currency;
        ExchangeRate = exchangeRate;
    }
}
```

I would like to achieve something like that:

```
public class CurrencyResolver : ValueResolver<int, int, CurrencyDetails>
{
    protected override Currency ResolveCore(int currencyId, int exchangeRateId)
    {
        var currency = new Currency(currencyId); //simplified logic
        var exchangeRate = new ExchangeRate(exchangeRateId);

        var currencyDetails = new CurrencyDetails(currency, exchangeRate);
        return currencyDetails;
    }
}
```

I know that I can pass the whole object as the source object, but for me it is not a solution:

```
ValueResolver<Document, Currency>
```

I can't use full object, because I have many document types and i don't want to create new resolver for each document. 
Ignoring the element (for manual conversion) is also not allowed in my case. Currency conversion logic must be conducted by AutoMapper.

**It's important for me that the conversion took place in background (during the conversion of the main subject).**

For example:

```
Document document;
var documentDto = Mapper.Map<DocumentDto>(document); // and in this moment i have proper CurrencyDetails object!
```

Thank you for your advice.

### My solutions

I figured two solutions, but I dont like them (soooo dirty)

**Solution 1** - wrap a class with interface:

```
public interface ICurrencyHolder
{
    int CurrencyId {get; set;}
    int ExchangeRateId {get; set;}
}

public class Document : ICurrencyHolder
{
    public int CurrencyId {get; set;}
    public int ExchangeRateId {get; set;}
}
```

and use resolver with following parameters:

```
ValueResolver<ICurrencyHolder, Currency>
```

**Solution 2** - take as source element object type and take values via reflection

```
ValueResolver<object, Currency>
```

This is terrible!

Answer (score 8):

If I understand correctly, you need to do the following mapping: from (`CurrencyId`, `ExchangeRateId`) to `Currency`. You can achieve it using `Tuple` ([it is a standard .Net class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) very handy in these cases):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Tuple<int,int>, Currency>()
   .ForMember(x => x.Currency, cfg => cfg.MapFrom(y => new Currency(y.Item1, y.Item2));
```

Invoke the mapper as follows:

```
Mapper.Map<Tuple<int,int>, Currency>(Tuple.Create(doc.CurrencyId, doc.ExchangeRateId));
```

Comment: It's good solution, but in single document i have 3-4 cases like this and i wouldn't map this properties in manual way. I want create map on the main object (using some resolvers or not) and after mapping get the full object in the correct state.

Answer (score 2):

Maybee you can map it like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
      .ConstructUsing(s => Mapper.Map<Source, Currency>(s));

Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Currency>()
      .ForMember(dst => dst.CurrencySymbol, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.DocumentDto.CurrencySymbol))
      .ForMember(dst => dst.ExchangeRate , map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Document.ExchangeRate ));
```

Also possible:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
      .ConstructUsing(s => Mapper.Map<Source, Currency>(s));

Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Currency>()
      .ConstructUsing(s => Mapper.Map<DocumentDto, Currency>(s))
      .ConstructUsing(s => Mapper.Map<Document, Currency>(s));

Mapper.CreateMap<DocumentDto, Currency>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Document, Currency>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you will be doing this for every document type:

```
Document document;
var documentDto = Mapper.Map<DocumentDto>(document);
```

Then you will have to define mappings for each one of them. So I'd definitely go with the ICurrencyHolder idea and use a resolver like this:

**The resolver**

```
public class CurrencyResolver : ValueResolver<ICurrencyHolder, Currency>
{
    protected override Currency ResolveCore(ICurrencyHolder source)
    {
        return new Currency(source.CurrencyId, source.ExchangeRateId);
    }
}
```

**Document "types"**

```
public class Document : ICurrencyHolder
{
    public int CurrencyId { get; set; }
    public int ExchangeRateId { get; set; }
}

public class ExtendedDocument : ICurrencyHolder
{
    public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }
    public int CurrencyId { get; set; }
    public int ExchangeRateId { get; set; }
}

public interface ICurrencyHolder
{
    int CurrencyId { get; set; }
    int ExchangeRateId { get; set; }
}
```

**And the mappings:**

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Document, DocumentDto>().ForMember(m => m.Currency, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CurrencyResolver>());
Mapper.CreateMap<ExtendedDocument, DocumentDto>().ForMember(m => m.Currency, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CurrencyResolver>());
```

With that in place you can create your dto's like this and get the Currency resolve itself for you at the mapping stage:

```
var dto = Mapper.Map<DocumentDto>(document);
var extendedDto = Mapper.Map<DocumentDto>(extendedDocument);
```